# Threads in kernel space

Tags: c, multithreading, kernel-module

I want to make thread for keepalive timer in kernel space. But there are some problems:

1) KThreads: in my callback function i make loop

```
while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
    // some work
    unsigned long j0, j1;
    int delay = 5*HZ;
    j0 = jiffies;
    j1 = j0 + delay;
    printk("\n----------thread print----------");

    while (time_before(jiffies, j1))
            schedule();
    }
}
```

but when i call kthread_stop(keep_timer) in module, it awaits for kthread to stop and i loose from 0 to delay seconds. It is a disaster for my module to await for so long

2) Tasklet: tasklets are ATOMIC and i cannot make it wait for delay-seconds inside callback function

How else can i make a thread with timer and a callback function, which will be in a continious loop until it is killed from module without waiting to thread to stop?

Comment: Just add condition `!kthread_should_stop()` to inner wait (via `&&` operation).

Comment: You could wait for a completion variableof type `struct completion`(say, `struct completion keep_completion`) with a timeout. Then instead of doing `while (time_before(jiffies, j1)) schedule();`, do `wait_for_completion_timeout(&keep_completion, delay);`. The completion variable needs to be initialized first by calling `init_completion(&keep_completion);`. To stop the thread, call `complete(&keep_completion);` followed by your `kthread_stop(keep_timer);`. You can re-use the completion variable later by calling `reinit_completion(&keep_completion);`. This stuff is in `<linux/completion.h>`.